# using の after　について・に対して

Tags: grammar, particle-の, academic-japanese

Recently I've made two similar mistakes. 1 and 2 show my original sentences while 3 and 4 are the sentences with my 先生's revisions added. I don't really understand why the の needs to be added after a noun (I haven't been able to find similar examples online). Can someone explain?

Original:

> 1. 特に、児童福祉と関連の活動をしたり、多発性硬化症について研究ためにも寄付もします。
> 2. 彼に対して第一印象はどうでしたか？

Revised:

> 3. 特に、児童福祉と関連の活動をしたり、多発性硬化症について**の**研究ためにも寄付もします。
> 4. 彼に対して**の**第一印象はどうでしたか？

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is very simple.  It is because the phrase before the 「の」 modifies a ***noun*** in each of the two sentences.  **Only 「の」 can connect a modifier to a noun**.

> 「多発性硬化症について**の**研究」

is correct because 「研究」 is a noun.  **Without a 「の」, the following word must be a verb** as in:

> 「多発性硬化症について研究**する/した/している**, etc.」

BTW, your teacher overlooked two more mistakes.

1) You need to use another 「の」 right ***after*** the 「研究」 as well.  It is incorrect to say 「研究ためにも」.

2) You should ***not*** use a 「も」 on both sides of the 「寄付」.  Drop the first one.

To sum up, here is what is correct:

Correct: 「多発性硬化症について**の**研究**の**ために寄付もします」

Correct: 「多発性硬化症について研究するために寄付もします」

A switch from 「研究」(noun) to 「研究する」(verb)  causes the grammatical changes above.

Moving on to your second sentence..

「第一印象」is, of course, a noun; therefore, you need to say 「彼に対して**の**第一印象」.

Like I showed with the frst sentence, you could do away with the 「の」 if you correctly changed the grammar of the sentence around.  You can say:

> 「彼に対して、どんな第一印象を持ちましたか。」

Here, 「彼に対して」 modifies 「持ちました」, which once again is a verb.

Answer (score 1):

The の is your good old noun modifier. Lets examine the following 2 example sentences, one using 「について」and one using 「についての」:

> １.車についてマニュアルを参照{さんしょう}した　　
>   ２.車についてのマニュアルを参照{さんしょう}した

The first sentence translates to something like: "I consulted the manual about the car". As in, I went and looked up information in the manual looking for information about something to do with cars.

The second sentence translates to something like: "I consulted the car manual". As in, it is a manual concerning cars.

If you are looking for more example sentences [jisho](http://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6%E3%81%AE%20%23sentences) has a cool function that allows you to search for sentences containing a specific word.

Comment: `参照しった` -- 「参照した」って書こうとなさったんでは？

Comment: It seems i made a conjugation mistake, should indeed have been 「参照した」. I was trying to come up with some example that would work either way to show the difference, and though consulting some medium about something would work. Was i wrong?